# best way to store a lot of information in a database c#

Tags: c#, arrays, database, datatable

I want to create a database which contains packs, each pack contains 50 levels, each level has the information of 2D integer array and 2D Boolean array.

How can I store all those arrays in a way I can access them easily?

My app is creating an `int[,]` array and a `bool[,]` array from the users input and I want those arrays to be saved on a level the user chose that on a pack the user chose..

I thought maybe making data table for each Pack with a column for its pack, column with level number(1-50) and 2 string columns with the arrays translated to a long string, but it looks just too messy..

```
DataTable Pack1= new DataTable();
Pack1.Columns.Add("level",typeof(int));
Pack1.Columns.Add("Pack",typeof(int));
Pack1.Columns.Add("intarr",typeof(string));
Pack1.Columns.Add("boolarr",typeof(string));
Pack1.Rows.Add(1,1,"1,2,0,1,2,0,2,3,0,-1,2,1,5,3,2,1",
"f,t,f,f,t,f,f,f,t,f,t,t,f,t,f,t");
Pack1.Rows.Add(2,1,"1,2,3,2,1,-1,2,3,1,4,2,3,1,5,-1,-1",
"t,f,f,f,t,f,t,t,f,f,t,t,f,t,f,f");
```

and so on..
I was hoping for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Such data is not a good fit for storing in table form, because it has no relational or hierarchical structure. Store whole arrays as blobs, either in the database or in flat files.

Comment: could you please give me an example or send me a link of an article i can use? because i dont really familliar with blobs..

Comment: @JonatanSv. This boils down to either designing your own file format, and/or serializing your data structures.

Comment: I don't know any articles to recommend. Most database bindings and ORMs, including `DataTable`, understand blob columns and use `byte[]` as the corresponding CLR type. You can use `Buffer.ByteLength` and `Buffer.BlockCopy` to convert between your integer/boolean arrays and `byte[]`s.